# In a flow chart, is there a convention on directionality of true/false conditions from a decision?

Tags: workflows, user-experience, flowchart

When writing a flow chart, I can understand that it is a best practice to generally read left-to-right or right-to-left per locale, and/or top-to-bottom and generally for the directional flow of the chart to be consistent.

But, when it comes to a diamond ("decision") element and its yes/no or true/false result arrows, is there a convention as to which one ought to be pointing down and which one to the side?

Comment: As far as I know, no.  But I can't say that with any authority.  Either way, whether there is or isn't - the important thing is to be consistent - even if your graph is different from many others, it will still be readable.

Comment: No. You just “label” the outgoing arrows with T/F or Y/N and the like to say which is which.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is such a convention, but it is not based on true or false. The "happy flow" will always be pointing down and any exceptional or side-tracked flow will be pointing left/right.

E.g. if you have a decision based on whether you are having to set up a new client or use an existing client, the existing client is the nice direction ==> go down.

Comment: Thank you very much. I never found this information searching online.

Comment: One advantage of this convention, especially when laying out steps and decisions from left-to-right is that decisions that require "going back" to a step can have the arrow loop around back to a previous step, while the "happy flow" continues down. This can limit arrows crossing over each other. Flipping the convention might work, but then arrows could start crossing more shapes (since you're laying out shapes top-to-bottom already).

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such convention. I have even seen flowcharts where both the yes and no (or true and false) arrows attached to the side of a decision element.

It all depends on how you can best get the idea across that you are showing in the diagram.